# Ramda pipe with dynamic function

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

```
var arr = [functionA(), functionB(), functionC()]
var data = { /** some data */ }
```

How can I dynamically add the functions from the arr list and add it to ramda pipe.

Expected code:

```
const newFn = pipe(functionA, functionB, functionC)

newFn(data)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`apply`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#apply):

```js
const buildPipe = apply(pipe);
const add3 = buildPipe([inc, inc, inc]);
const add4 = buildPipe([inc, inc, inc, inc]);

console.log(add3(1));
console.log(add4(2));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script>const {apply, pipe, inc} = R;</script>
```

Comment: as mentioned in another post, native [`function.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) will also work the same as using `R.apply` function.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the **es6 spread operator** which will spread out the array items as arguments to the pipe function.

Also, don't call your functions in the array unless they are returning a function that you want :)

```
const arr = [functionA, functionB, functionC]
const data = { /** some data */ }

const newFn = pipe(...arr)

newFn(data)
```