# Pass a list of functions to pipe or compose in Ramda.js

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

About functions that take multiple arguments.

In particular I assume "pipe" and "compose".
They take multiple functions as arguments.

At this time, I want to pass them a list of multiple functions.

In Ramda.js
Normally:

```
const piped = R.pipe(R.inc, R.negate);
```

I wanna like this:

```
const funcs = [R.inc, R.negate];
const piped = R.pipe(funcs);
```

I'm also thinking about passing a list of partially applied functions

```
const funcs = [R.add (1), R.pow (2)];
```

The functions in these lists have no name property.
So I wondered if a solution could be found by binding these Ramdajs functions and partially applied functions to variables.
But they didn't seem so smart.

This is my first experience in English and in stack overflow.
And I am sorry in ugly English because it is a mechanical translation.
How can I solve this problem, please tell me the solution.
Thank you.

Comment: how about `piped  = R.pipe.apply(R, funcs);` ??

Comment: Wow.
I was surprised that you could get an answer so quickly.
I had no idea of the code you taught me.
I am very grateful to you.
And thanks for the stack overflow.

Comment: Great, please accept the answer and read on the documentation given there to learn more

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ramda pipe with dynamic function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55114642/ramda-pipe-with-dynamic-function)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Ramda.js](https://github.com/ramda/ramda) functions are normal javascript functions so `Function.call` and [`Function.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) methods are available.

So the solution to your problem is to use `.apply` method to apply multiple arguments (that are a list):

example:

```
const funcs = [R.inc, R.negate];
const piped = R.pipe.apply(R, funcs);
```

There is also a [`Ramda.apply`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#apply) as well (which you can check in the Ramda documentation) but native `Function.apply` method solves the problem elegantly and natively (**note** according to documentation of the [`pipe` function](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#pipe) there is no mention of using a specific context as there is for some other functions in `Ramda` documentation ).

**Answer to comment:**

`R.apply` has exactly same issues with bound context as native `apply` method has (according to [Ramda documentation](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#apply)). So the issue of context of `apply` method is mostly irrelevant and of minor importance.

Comment: Works with more than two functions.
FP is deep and interesting.
I will read more about the Ramdajs documentation and more.
Thank you for teaching me a lot.

Comment: yes works with arbitrary amount of arguments passed as array

Comment: I would do `R.apply(R.pipe)([/* list of functions */])` instead. The caveat with your approach is that you're assuming that `R` is the actual context for this function which may or may bot be true. It's better to not assume anything about the internals of a library IMHO.

Comment: @customcommander, context is mostly irrelevant for functional code including Ramda.js, (in documentation it is mentioned as such) plus ramda.js functions can be used out of the R context as well. So i find this comment mostly of very minor importance. Also one can use null as `this` context. The fact remains that ramda functions are normal javascript functions where `apply` method can be used.. Of course one can also use some ramda functions that have similar functionality one can delve into the documentation. But still `apply` method solves the problem with native methods

Comment: @customcommander `R.apply` has exactly same issues with bound context as native `apply` method has (check [Ramda documentation](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#apply)). So I find the comment mostly irrelevant and of minor importance

Answer (score 2):

The simplest method to convert an array into multiple parameters is destructuring. Add "..." in front of the parameter:

```
const funcs = [R.inc, R.negate];
const piped = R.pipe(...funcs);
```

More about destructuring here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Answer (score 1):

What you actually want is to fold a list of functions with the reverse function composition combinbator (aka contravariant functor):

```js
const inc = x => x + 1;
const sqr = x => x * x;

const reduce1 = f => xs =>
  xs.reduce(f);
  
const contra = (g, f) => x =>
  f(g(x));

console.log(
  reduce1(contra) ([inc, inc, inc, sqr]) (1)); // 16
```

This works only for non-empty arrays. We need a fold with an accumulator to make the partially applied fold `reduce1(contra)` a total function:

```js
const inc = x => x + 1;
const sqr = x => x * x;
const id = x => x;

const reduce = f => acc => xs =>
  xs.reduce(f, acc);
  
const contra = (g, f) => x =>
  f(g(x));
  
const pipen = reduce(contra) (id);

console.log(
  pipen([inc, inc, inc, sqr]) (1)); // 16

console.log(
  pipen([]) (1)); // 1
```

In Ramda though, using `R.apply` is totally fine. But note that this function is specific to Ramda.

Comment: One very slight caveat to this approach is that `reduce` might not be as reusable as one might assume.  It should usually work.  But if someone passed it a function that did something odd with a third or fourth parameter, the call to `Array.prototype.reduce` would yield that odd behavior.  Perhaps safer would be `const reduce = f => acc => xs => xs.reduce((a, x) => f(a, x), acc)`.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Agreed. On the other hand, providing context (i.e. index + original array) is sometimes reasonable. I guess it's a tradeoff between safety/predictablility and expressivness.

Comment: Absolutely; there are times when it makes sense.  It's just the ghost of `['1', '2', '3'].map(parseInt)` that makes me worry.